# Hyperlink from one Angular App to another Angular App

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have two different Angular Apps and one App is redirecting to the other App using a hyperlink to a specific route. However, the system is throwing a Whitelabel Error Page. The empty path has no issue.

I used the default HTML 5 location strategy for the routing.

first app: "http://www.app1.com/"
second app: "http://www.app2.com/"

the first app redirects to the second app thru:
window.location.href = "http://www.app2.com/some-path";

This is my sample route in the second app:

```
{
    path: 'some-path',
    component: SomeComponent,

  },
{
    path: '',
    component: SomeEmptyComponent,

  }
```

Comment: Are apps deployed on different locations?
How second app routing look like?
How hyperlink look like?

Comment: @AkifHadziabdic yes, they are deployed in different locations. The calling application uses this: window.location.href = "http://www.app2.com/some-path" ;

Comment: Can you explain how did you deploy apps? 
Do you have some auth system on apps like spring security on backend side?
Can you share you a html tag?
Can you open same url if you put url directly in browser?

Answer (score 2):

Use href for any other application

```
<a class=" href=""></a>
```

you can use relative path e.g

```
 <a class=" href="#/list?Id=2"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Internal link (should match your routing config):

```
<a [routerLink]="['/some-path']" [queryParams]="{debug: true}">Some path</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/']" [queryParams]="{debug: true}">Home</a>
```

External link (should contain absolute path or relative which link other app):

```
<a href="www.facebook.com/yourpage">Facebook</a>
```